# Find X occurence of string in file and replace to static string

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sed

I need you help again. I need to find 3 and 4 occurrence of comma (accross the line) and replace with specific string, let's assume:

```
"Text","Text2","Text3","Text4","Text5"
"Text6","Text7","Text8","Text9","Text10"
```

Now, I would like to replace Text4,Text9,Text5,Text10 to eg. "Static"

```
 "Text","Text2","Text3","Static","Static"
 "Text6","Text7","Text8","Static","Static"
```

Which function should I use? Know that probably 'sed' is proper to do that, but how to count commas?

EDIT: (simpler version with only 3 occurence of comma)

I need to find ONLY 3 occurrence of comma (accross the line) and replace with specific string, let's assume:

```
"Text","Text2","Text3","Text4","Text5"
"Text6","Text7","Text8","Text9","Text10"
```

Now, I would like to replace Text4,Text9 to eg. "Static"

```
 "Text","Text2","Text3","Static","Text5"
 "Text6","Text7","Text8","Static","Text5"
```

Comment: it is always the 3rd 4th comma or the last two fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This awk one-liner works for the given example. It changes the text in 4th and 5th columns/fields:

```
awk -F, -v OFS="," '{i=4;while(i<6)gsub(/\w+/,"Static",$(i++))}7' file
```

Comment: Thanks Kent, On more question, How it would looks like if I would know that I want to change only string after 3 occurrence of comma? Probably it will make the code simpler without while,i++ things.

Comment: @maciek2791 I don't get what you meant... if it is about requirement, pls edit your question.

Comment: Edited, I meant simpler version (only with 3 occurence), take a look.

Comment: @maciek2791 `awk -F, -v OFS="," '7+gsub(/\w+/,"Static",$4)' file`

Comment: Kent, Now I found out that your solution display proper output, But I would like to change it in file... how to do that ?

Comment: @maciek2791  `awk '...' file > tmp && mv tmp file`

Comment: thanks a lot!, but... I have one more question : ( Instead of $4 I want to get this value from variable. Let's assume  I have Variable1=3   , Variable2="$""$Variable1" , result of echo Variable2 is $3. Now I'm trying to put it to your AWK solution.   awk '...,Static",$Variable2    . But it replace all columns to static

Comment: @maciek2791 do some search, how to bring shell var to awk. I 've answered those questions here at SO at least twice.